# Handling server-side validation with Ajax forms and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

Before down-voting or closing for duplicate questions, I want to make clear that I have read old posts on this site and others. The problem is that they *are* old (some at least) and are not giving really good examples.

I currently use ASP.Net MVC 2.0 with `Ajax.BeginForm` and `jQuery Validation` client-side validation which both works perfectly fine. But I would like server-side validation errors to be displayed like client-side errors (not necessarily remote). The server-side errors are currently applied with `ModelState.AddModelError`.

I use code which extends something like this:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

using (Ajax.BeginForm("Bar", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "result"})) { %>
<fieldset>
    <p>
        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Foo) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foo) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And, as I mentioned, I set the errors with `ModelState.AddModelError`. Currently, I return a validation-summary on error (which does not bind to the elements which causes them) and otherwise return my result.

Until now, I have encountered multiple solutions to this problem:

- xVal (supports remote server-validation)
- Set the entire form in a `RenderPartial` and `id='result'`.
- Return some JSON with result and error-messages

But is there really not a better solution (maybe in ASP.Net MVC 3.0)? Is xVal still a good solution (not a lot of development is going on)?

If I go with a JSON solution, is there a jQuery-way to assign errors to specific elements which mimics 100% the client-side validation?

If there is any better solution, I'm prepared to switch the technologies I use.

Thanks, Lasse Espeholt

Comment: I don't think anything "new" has happened with client side validation since the release of MVC 2 so I'm not sure what kind of new information your looking for.

Comment: @jfar xVal was made for 1.0 but is this still a good choice? I see last update to it was 1 year ago. I'm looking for recommendation on which solution I should use of the three (or other solutions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xVal is good!  I'm using it with 2 asp.net mvc 2 projects and it works wonderfully.

Comment: Can it fall-back if no javascript is enabled? And, I need to check field for valid XML which takes some computation. As I understand it, it will probe some server-side validations before actually make the form-submit call, is this correct? Is it then possible to cache a result which is computed on validation so it can be used when the actual submit is invoked?

Comment: xVal does have support for validation that needs to go to the server to be checked.  look up the remote validation functionality.   not sure about caching.